# Liferay/Icefaces portlet doesn't allow to access in doView methods

Tags: liferay, portlet, icefaces, managed-bean, portletbridge

I have a problem with the access at the doView() methods. 
I've made up  a portlet using Liferay 6.3 as CMS, ICEFACES 3.3.0 and tomcat 7. I used a **liferay-faces-bridge** in order to use Icefaces framework in Liferay. For this reason i have setted up the portlet.xml in this way:

```
<portlet>
            <portlet-name>FinalTest</portlet-name>
            <display-name>FinalTest</display-name>
            <portlet-class>org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet</portlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
                <value>/index.xhtml</value>
            </init-param>
            <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
            <supports>
                <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            </supports>
            <portlet-info>
                <title>FinalENELTest</title>
                <short-title>FinalENELTest</short-title>
                <keywords>FinalENELTest</keywords>
            </portlet-info>
            <security-role-ref>
                <role-name>administrator</role-name>
            </security-role-ref>
            <security-role-ref>
                <role-name>guest</role-name>
            </security-role-ref>
            <security-role-ref>
                <role-name>power-user</role-name>
            </security-role-ref>
            <security-role-ref>
                <role-name>user</role-name>
            </security-role-ref>
        </portlet>
```

Also I have a ManagedBean like this (for the business logic):

```
@ManagedBean(name="backingBean")
@SessionScoped
public class BackingBeanImpl extends GenericPortlet{ 

          .... 

    @Override
protected void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
        throws PortletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("I'M HERE");
    super.doView(request, response);
}

}
```

The problem is that when the portlet starts the doView() method  is not invoked. Maybe it is a bridge problem. I don't know.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your portlet implementation - according to the portlet.xml that you list - is `org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet`. Just because your backing bean implements GenericPortlet does not make it the portlet's implementation. doView is implemented in the referenced portlet, not in your class.

If you want to override `GenericPortlet` methods, you shouldn't use JSF. Corollary of that: If you use JSF, use the JSF style controllers to access your business logic.

By the way: You shouldn't put your business logic into a portlet, rather make the portlet access your business logic. Don't have your business logic reference the portlet api: That would restrict your business logic to run only in that environment.